# typescript - how to sum two typeof number

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have tried to sum two `typeof number` for using dynamic number value type

but I couldn't get any solution

for example,

`const num1 = 12`

`Type TotalNum<T extends number> = T & typeof num1` like this

and result is `TotalNum<2> = 14`

anyone know how to sum like this

Comment: https://itnext.io/implementing-arithmetic-within-typescripts-type-system-a1ef140a6f6f

Comment: TS doesn't directly support type-level arithmetic; there is a feature request at [ms/TS#26382](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382). If you use small non-negative integers then you can manipulate tuple types as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/Wyledm) shows. There are even crazy ways to do arithmetic with template literal types, which work for arbitrary numbers, but that's almost certainly overkill (and would take a while to implement). Does that fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)